# Is a minimal deviation version of set partition problem NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, partitions

I want to know if a specific version (and **what´s its name?**) of the *Set Partitioning Problem* is NP-Complete, and if, is NP-Hard?

**Problem**:

Given a set of elements $e_i$ where $i={1,...,n}$, each with an associated weight $w(e_i)$, we want to find an optimum partition of these elements into a set of $S_j$ subsets where $j={1,...,k}$. Each subset $S_j$ has an objective weight $W_j$. We define a subset's weight as $w(S_j) = \sum_{{e_i}\in{S_j}} w(e_i)$ where $w(S_j)=0$ if and only if $S_j=\emptyset$.
Then the objective is to **minimize** the sum of the absolute deviation of the weights $w(S_j)$ w.r.t. the objective weights $W_j$:

$$min \sum_{j=1}^{k} |w(S_j) - W_j|$$

I do not really need a proof, just an actual answer and if possible, some reference to a paper or an article about it.

Comment: How are the $W_j$'s given? Since there are exponentially many, it is important to specify this. If for example they are given by an efficient program which takes a subset as input and outputs its weight, then the decision version of your problem is NP hard, by a reduction from subset sum. Given a subset sum instance with value $k$ and sum of all elements $s$, set the weight of all subsets whose sum is not $s-k$, $k$ to infinity.

Comment: @Ariel There are only $k$ many values $W_j$, namely $W_1,\ldots,W_k$.

Comment: Your problem is NP-hard by reduction from SUBSET-SUM.

Comment: @Ariel, suppose the wheight is previously set array.. Thanks for the comments! Do you have a name for the problem?